# How to only get file names matching a pattern

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this below function which looks for the files in the directory.

```
files = list(filter(lambda f: fnmatch.fnmatch(f, FILENAME +"*"), os.listdir(SRC_DIR)
```

Here is the example of how it looks

```
['data.txt',data.done,data_audit.done, data1.trans]
```

I want to exclude all the .Done files. How do I remove all the .done files from the list?

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: a little unclear because of `FILENAME` not being defined, is the goal to keep all files that begin with `data` but do not end with `.done`?

Comment: Try this: `list(filter(lambda f: not f.endswith('.done'), os.listdir(SRC_DIR)))`

Comment: Side-note: If you need a `lambda` to use `map`/`filter`, don't. Just use an equivalent list comprehension or generator expression (which can inline the contents of the `lambda` and thereby run faster). `map`/`filter` are basically only appropriate when an existing function does *exactly* what you need, and only provide non-trivial performance benefits if said function is a built-in implemented in C.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a list comprehension with a filter on a pair of conditions for what I would consider to be the simplest solution.

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir(SRC_DIR)
         if f.startswith('data') and not f.endswith('.done')]
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. But I am getting this error. I am on Python 2.7.  "Unicode object has not attribute 'endwith"

Comment: you tagged your question as python-3.x, but that is a Python 2 error. Are you intentionally running Python 2 (if so, change the tags)? Or are you trying to use Python 3?

Comment: Sorry Ryan my bad. By mistake I tagged as Python3.X, We are using python 2.7

Comment: It looks like you just typo'd **end**with instead of **ends**with

Answer (score 1):

With Python 3.5+, consider using [Pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). Your example then becomes:

```
import pathlib as pl
files=[fn for fn in pl.Path("/path_to_dir").glob("data*") if fn.suffix!='.done']
```

For the current working directory:

```
files=[fn for fn in pl.Path.cwd().glob("data*") if fn.suffix!='.done']
```

And the returned files will all be absolute.

If there is a possibility that non files match that glob, you can add:

```
files=[fn for fn in pl.Path("/path_to_dir").glob("data*") 
                     if fn.suffix!='.done' and fn.is_file()]
```

Advantage over `os` and `glob` modules:

1. No need to import `glob` module to support file globbing;
2. The glob is handled by the os, so you do not need to filter ALL the files;
3. Consistent treatment of paths so there are fewer mistakes with relative paths;
4. Recursive searching and globbing is supported (similar to `os.walk` but a bit more simple).

Disadvantages:

1. Really should be Python 3.6+ since Path support was then added to `os` and `shutil`;
2. No native `chdir` -- you have to do `from os import chdir` to be able to change the working directory of the script.

Comment: Thank you so much I am on python 2.7 :)

Comment: Thanks! Do we need to use the "suffix" function? This should work too: `files=[fn for fn in pl.Path.cwd().glob("data*.done")]`

Comment: @arquillos: A glob works too! But the goal was to *exclude* `.done` files. Hence the suffix with the `!=`. Globs works better to *include* a pattern.